# Vaadin: Is there any way to hide the PWA dialog and to add a button to install it somewhere else?

Tags: java, dialog, installation, vaadin, progressive-web-apps

I want to hide the PWA dialog that comes up every time I get in my app pages:

[image]

Is there any way to do that? I can't find it in the documentations, and also... how do I add a way of installing it with a separate button, like...

```
button.addClickListener(click -> installPWA());
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There is [issue #5530](https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/5530) for hiding the install dialog. The issue is still open, but there is a workaround for hiding it through CSS.

Then there is [issue #6899](https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/6899) for enabling developers to make a button for the install. This issue is also open.

You can react with a thumbs up on the issues to show that they are important to you.

Comment: Awesome @Tazavoo, thanks man! I'll be waiting for the ability to install the PWA with a button, just like the TaskMob app